# Asp.net MVC with Ajax button to retrieve data from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I have an Ajax button that whenever I click it, it shows a single record from the database (in my Controller I used .Take(1) )
Here is my view :

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function ClearResults() {
            $("#current").empty();
        }
    </script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <h2 class="header-text">CURRENT</h2>
            <div class="current" id="current">
               X000
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                HttpMethod = "GET",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                UpdateTargetId = "current",
                                LoadingElementId = "loading",
                                OnBegin = "ClearResults",
                                }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1"})
</div>
```

Here is my controller for the button :

```
    public PartialViewResult BtnNext(int count = 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var model = db.Queues.OrderBy(x => x.QueueNumber).Take(1);
        return PartialView("_queuenumber", model);
    }
```

What I would like to do here is - whenever I click the next button it will display the first record from the database, then when I click it again it will show the second record and so on..
(as of now it only show the first data from database)

I wonder if that is even possible and what kind of stuff should I use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to track the current index client-side (JavaScript) or in the Model (Razor), then pass that into your controller method, incrementing the value with each call. From the server side you would do something like:

```
var model = db.Queues.OrderBy(x => x.QueueNumber).Skip(index).Take(1);
```

I'd recommend sending back a ViewModel. For the Razor implementation you could have a ViewModel that contains the displayed values, the Queue ID, and the index. I.e.

```
public class QueueViewModel
{
    public int QueueId { get; set; }
    public int QueueNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    // ..
    public int NextIndex { get; set; }
}

public PartialViewResult BtnNext(int index = 0)
{
    var model = db.Queues.OrderBy(x => x.QueueNumber)
        .Select(x => new QueueViewModel
        {
            QueueId = x.QueueId,
            QueueNumber = x.QueueNumber,
            Name = x.Name,
            NextIndex = index + 1
        })
        .Skip(index).Take(1);
    return PartialView("_queuenumber", model);
}
```

Then in the view would be something like below: (Sorry, my Razor is pretty rusty)

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", "QueueController", 
        new { index = Model.nextIndex },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "current",
            LoadingElementId = "loading",
            OnBegin = "ClearResults",
        }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1"})
```

This would need some verification for behaviour to ensure that the first call goes through with an index value of "0", but should hopefully give you some ideas to pursue.

Comment: I wonder why NextIndex = index + 1 doesn't work?  
and .Skip(index).Take(1);

Comment: if your method signature still has "count" as the parameter name, I'd re-labelled that to "index" as it was more descriptive of what the value was.

Comment: it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you paste your updated code? A null ref exception doesn't make any sense for a view model property assignment to an integer.

Comment: my system at this point already have a QueueNumber in the database, I need to get that and show it to the view 1 by 1

Comment: Ok, so you want to use the QueueNumber as the index to iterate over and can guarantee that there will be no gaps in the sequence? (it will be 1,2,3,4,  not possibly 1,2,4,5 etc. i.e. items in the queue cannot be deleted without this queue number sequence being re-calculated.)

Comment: sir @Steve Py i Need something just like this. I cant convert that to ASP.NET im still a newbie http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2015/03/How-To-Make-MySQL-Database-Navigation-Buttons-In-C.html